# How to configure Jenkins deployment path on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, jenkins

With [default Ubuntu/Debian installation of Jenkins](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/), **is there an easy way to change the deployment path**? I'd like Jenkins to be available somewhere like `http://localhost:8090/foobar`

I'm looking for a way to configure it in **`/etc/default/jenkins`**, similarly to setting the HTTP port:

```
# port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
HTTP_PORT=8090
```

`/etc/default/jenkins` contains this bit which seems related, but I'm not sure how to use it:

```
# servlet context, important if you want to use apache proxying  
PREFIX=/jenkins
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, looking at `/etc/default/jenkins` a bit more, this turned out very easy.

The end of  `/etc/default/jenkins` looks like this by default:

```
# servlet context, important if you want to use apache proxying  
PREFIX=/jenkins

# arguments to pass to jenkins.
# --javahome=$JAVA_HOME
# --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT (default 8080; disable with -1)
# --httpsPort=$HTTP_PORT
# --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT
# --argumentsRealm.passwd.$ADMIN_USER=[password]
# --argumentsRealm.roles.$ADMIN_USER=admin
# --webroot=~/.jenkins/war
# --prefix=$PREFIX

JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"
```

So, you only need to set `PREFIX` to your liking, and **edit `JENKINS_ARGS` to contain `--prefix=$PREFIX`**. So `JENKINS_ARGS` would be something like:

```
 JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --prefix=$PREFIX --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"
```